# Achieving Concurrency using Pika and python2.7 --

Tags: multithreading, rabbitmq

- I have an application that lets users upload upto 200 documents/resumes.
- The objective of the application is to return a parsed and scored result for each of these documents.
- The front end splits these 200 documents into batches of 10. i.e 20 messages are put into a queue(RabbitMQ).
- I have a 6 worker processes listening to the queue( scripts that are triggered by an entry_point).
- The workers take the message and splits the resumes if it is a batch message. If it is not a batch message, the worker starts processing the message. ( the average time for the processing is around 8 secs).
- The queue gets piled up with 200 resumes and the 6 workers get 5 messages. Processing each message sequentially.
- Which means, if another user uploads even 1 resume,one of the workers needs to reach the end of the queue to pick that message and the user is left waiting till the processing of the 200 resumes.
- I'm doing this using Rabbitmq,and python2.7.
- I'm using a blockingconnection to connect to the queue and process the messages.
- The only way to get to the last user's message is to complete the processing of all the message as fast as i can, which could mean more processes or more containers. When i fire up more proceatses using multiprocessing (pool of 6 workers), the cpu utilization is at the highest and cannot handle any more messages.
- How can i prevent my users from waiting for the response. Is adding more workers to listen and consume from the queue the only way?
- The consumer is just a plain consumer with no API. The tasks are directly picked from the queue and processed.
- More workers i add, the faster the queue is consumed. But still the user that had uploaded probably last still has to wait for a long time.

Comment: What is the response? Does it contains some results from the processing or it is just a confirmation that the document was received?

Comment: Exactly what @noxdafox said ... do your users really care about a response or can they come back and check later?

Comment: @LukeBakken 
Thank you for replying.
There are 2 types of responses 
1. The progress of the upload/processing is sent back to another queue which is being listened by a worker and displayed to the users.
2. Once the processing for that particular upload is complete, the users get back a result of the processing. 
3) There are 5 workers processing the messages from the queue in parallel, but the message in the end of the queue is not touched unless the messages before are completely done, thereby leaving the user who uploaded even 1 resume/document completely at loss.

Comment: "the message in the end of the queue is not touched unless the messages before are completely done" - that's how RabbitMQ works. You need to give your users a way to come back and check on progress rather than making them wait.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
I may need to rephrase my question a little more better.
I was looking at something on the lines of an asynchronous worker/consumer model, but as you rightly pointed out, that's how the queue works and that's why its called a queue.